# How to remove a "Private Protection Password" on an ANDROID MT6592, please?

Tags: password-protection

I guess one of my kids activated this kind of password that suddently appeared on my YHAPPY UP620.

The USB mode is not available, so that my PC does not see my phone, and I can not flash it...

How can I solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Its very simple. Try to press volume- & power key at a time the will  display a factory reset settings and click on rest and your mobile will be unlocked.

Comment: I think you should mention and stress that **this will delete user data as well including apps and their data**. Some folks, well, fails to understand the grammatical meaning of factory reset unless they perform the reset and face the consequences.

Comment: Yes! But in this procedure the mobile data will lose. But you want mobile safely not possible by normal lock removers.